# Add custom icon to leaflet-ajax data

Tags: ajax, leaflet

I need to add a custom icon to some JSON data I'm pulling into a leaflet map with leaflet-ajax (https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax) but can't figure out how to do it.

Any advice? Here's how I'm getting my data:

```
var geojsonLayerIncidents = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://131940.qld.gov.au/api/json/v1/events/incident");
var geojsonLayerRoadworks = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://131940.qld.gov.au/api/json/v1/events/roadworks");

geojsonLayerIncidents.addTo(map);
geojsonLayerIncidents.bindPopup("<b>Incident or accident</b><p>Avoid if possible<p>");
geojsonLayerRoadworks.addTo(map);
geojsonLayerRoadworks.bindPopup("<b>Roadworks</b><p>Avoid if possible");
```

I'd like to have a single icon for incidents and another for roadwork

Comment: Do you mean a custom marker for the JSON data?

Comment: See edits to original post but to answer your question, yes. I'd like an icon for incidents and another for roadwork markers. Thx

Comment: Check this out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113076/custom-marker-icon-based-on-attribute-data-in-leaflet-geojson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there can be other best ways to use custom icons in your scenario. But for now, you can try this way

First create a custom Icon like this

```
var baseballIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://leafletjs.com/examples/baseball-marker.png',
    iconSize: [32, 37],
    iconAnchor: [16, 37],
    popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});
```

Now, modify the way you're adding Ajax like below

```
var geojsonLayerIncidents = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://131940.qld.gov.au/api/json/v1/events/incident",{
                                middleware:function(data){
                                   return L.geoJson(data, {
                                      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                                        layer.setIcon(baseballIcon);
                                      }
                                    }).addTo(map);
                                }
                            });
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zafrii/8y9wh8ch/)